# Playing unsupported audio (.m4a / .m4v / .aif )

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

Is there any way to play .m4a files in Android ?

I have a music player application that can play .mp3 files, but it does not play .m4a files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Android supports m4a container: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html . But  it could contain variously encoded data. So you need to know particular codec not container.

Comment: im sorry but im very new to this topic i dont really have an idea. But  is there an existing codec that i can use? how do i implement it? T_T

Comment: If you're new then you should read some theory( http://www.techhive.com/article/213612/all_about_video_codecs_and_containers.html ).

Comment: Thanks for this man...it's really a big help. owe u one..

Comment: can i embed vlc player for my app? how do i use it? :(